# Swap data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with a query that allows me to swap data in the same column like this:

```
ID    Name     Notebook Sales  Pen Sales
 1     33             2             3
 2     33             5             6
 3     5              8             9
 4     7              2             3
 5     35             5             6
 6     35             8             9

ID    Name     Notebook Sales  Pen Sales
 1     35             2             3
 2     35             5             6
 3     5              8             9
 4     7              2             3
 5     33             5             6
 6     33             8             9
```

In this example i swapped the name '33' for the name '35' keeping the original info of each one.

I'm working with 5000+ rows so doing something one by one gonna take a while.

The only way i thougth was switching the ones with the name '33' to '35' but then im gonna end with something like this:

```
ID    Name     Notebook Sales  Pen Sales
 1     35             2             3
 2     35             5             6
 3     5              8             9
 4     7              2             3
 5     35             5             6
 6     35             8             9
```

and then they are going to mix making dificult to change the first '35' ones to '33'.

Hope you can help me out with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What determines if you swap the names? Why did 5 and 7 not get swapped?

Comment: i only want to swap the name  not the rest of the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single `update` (or `select` statement):

```
update t
    set name = (case when name = 33 then 35 else 33 end)
    where name in (33, 35);
```

In an update, the changes are not visible until they are statement ends and the changes are committed to the database.  As a result, the values on the right-hand side of the assignment are from the "old" version of the table.

Comment: We don't know that he only wants 35 for 33 and vice versa

Comment: @cronos2546 . . . Actually, I find the question pretty clear on that point.  The example is explicitly about these two values and there is nothing in the question about finding the switched values.

Comment: i didnt downvoted i would liek tho know why u got downvoted also

Comment: if the question isnt clear tell me so i can re-phrase it, and thanks for your help

Comment: His example did list 33 and 35 as the values to be changed, but he also specifies that he has many values. While the question does not state it, it is very likely, pending clarification, that there are other values to swap. If this were the case, the case statement would become onerous, and he should prepare a list of IDS which contain the original and swap IDs.

Comment: Which he could then join on the update. I will remove downvote if he actually just has two values

Comment: @cronos2546 . . . You should consider expending your energies on providing answers to questions, rather than downvoting and explaining.

Comment: @cronos2546..you should learn to answer before downvoting valid answers. Note that this is not a spoonfeeding forum, you get the idea and take it from there.

Comment: @vkp How do you know the answer was valid? It's totally unclear if OP wants just a single set of values swapped or has many more. Just throwing out an answer may not have fulfilled the question which would have required edits and revamping.

Comment: @cronos2546 I'm sure the OP can figure things out based on the answer on how to do it more generally.

Comment: thx @GordonLinoff your answer helped me a lot and i solved my problem.